# Reading a text file with multiple headers in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text file having multiple headers where "TEMP" column has the average temperature for the day, followed by the number of recordings. How can I read this text file properly to create a DataFrame

```
STN--- WBAN   YEARMODA    TEMP     
010010 99999  20060101    33.5 23
010010 99999  20060102    35.3 23
010010 99999  20060103    34.4 24
STN--- WBAN   YEARMODA    TEMP     
010010 99999  20060120    35.2 22
010010 99999  20060121    32.2 21
010010 99999  20060122    33.0 22
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you need this in a Spark DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can read the text file as a normal text file in an `RDD`
2. You have a separator in the text file, let's assume it's a `space`
3. Then you can remove the header from it
4. Remove all lines inequal to the header
5. Then convert the `RDD` to a dataframe using `.toDF(col_names)`

Like this:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("path/to/file.txt").map(lambda x: x.split(" ")) # step 1 & 2
headers = rdd.first() # Step 3
rdd2 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x != headers)
df = rdd2.toDF(headers) # Step 4
```

Comment: `rdd2 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x != headers)` holds true only if the `headers` are exactly same, every time they are repeated throughout the file. But then again, that's the best thing possible in the given case.

Comment: @KumarRohit Definitely, but OP sample data has the same headers, so I assumed. If not, we can still change the `filter` condition to whatever best suits OP's requirement

Comment: @pissall I am trying to read many of these text files into an rdd
`
    rdd = sc.textFile(readings_path+"/*").map(lambda x:x.split(" "))
    header = rdd.first()
    records = rdd.filter(lambda x: x!=header)
    readings = records.toDF(header)
    readings.show(5)
`
But i am getting an error at rdd.first(). Also the separator is not just a single space

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. I have tried on console.

```
val x = sc.textFile("hdfs path of text file")
val header = x.first()
var y = x.filter(x=>(!x.contains("STN"))) //this will remove all the line 
var df = y.toDF(header)
```

Hope this will works for you.