# skip multiple line of headers while reading multiple csv files in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read **multiple csv files** using spark. I need to **skip *more than one* line of header from each csv file**.
I am able to achieve this by below code.

```
            rdd = df.rdd
            schema = df.schema
            rdd_without_header = rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (row, index): index > skip_header).keys()
            df = spark_session.createDataFrame(rdd_without_header, schema=schema)
```

This code is working fine, but if I am having multiple compressed files of format gz this operation is taking very very long time to complete.
Difference is of magnitude 10x when using compressed file**s** as against non compressed file**s**.

*Since I want to skip multiple lines of header from all the files, I am not able to leverage the skip header option of spark*

```
option("header", "true")
```

What should be the best and optimized way to handle this use case.

Comment: Does this look similar to your query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066489/reading-a-text-file-with-multiple-headers-in-spark/59066751#comment104372594_59066751

Comment: if you know the schema of your file, you can use the classic `spark.read.csv` with `mode='DROPMALFORMED'` (works with the condition that there is at least one column which is not a string)

Comment: there is a small difference, i can have headers spanning multiple lines. Example i want to ready 5csv files from a given location and all csv files have first 3 lines as headers which i want to skip. @KumarRohit

Comment: Just give the path until the directory containing multiple CSVs. It'll work just fine then onwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip more then one lines of header in RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877326/how-to-skip-more-then-one-lines-of-header-in-rdd-in-spark). The most efficient option is `mapPartitionsWithIndex()`.